# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection - with Oracle 11gR2. Connecting with SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, redhat

I have installed Oracle 11g ON a RedHat6 linux instance, by following all the steps mentioned in "http://technologylair.net/2013/08/oracle-11g-installation-linux/#comment-50" I am trying to connect to the database from a remote machine using the sql developer. But always ending up with - "`IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`".

The parameters i am using are

```
Username: sys as sysdba 
Password: <oracle password> 
Hostname: IP address of the server on which Oracle SQL is installed. 
Port: 1521 
SID: testdb
```

I have also created a listener.ora file at location - "/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin", as it was not present before. Whose contents are -

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_TESTDB))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 173.39.238.15)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (TESTDB)
```

I have posted this question on dba.stackexchange too. but i need to get this resolved as soon as possible. and need help. Hence posting it here too.

Can you please tell me what i might be doing wrong.

Thanks.

**EDIT** the out put of "lsnrctl status"

> Connecting to
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_TESTDB)))
>   TNS-12541: TNS:no listener  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
>   TNS-00511: No listener    Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
>   Connecting to
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=173.39.238.15)(PORT=1521)))
>   TNS-12541: TNS:no listener  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
>   TNS-00511: No listener    Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Comment: Are you able to [ping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490968.aspx) the host `173.39.238.15`? This error means, the host you attempt to reach is not reachable.

Comment: yes, i can ping it .. also i have ssh access and working on it.

Comment: I have edited the question with the output of "lsnrctl status"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your listener is not running.  On the DB server, `ps -ef | grep lsnr` to see if there's a PID running `tnslsnr`.  If not, then you need to start the listener with `lsnrctl start`.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm from `ps eaf | grep lsnr` and its working, then run below probably a firewall is blocking your connection.

```
telnet hostname/IP 1521
Trying hostname/IP ...
telnet: connect to address hostname/IP: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If that is the case, then you need to get that checked.

Regards,