# starting oracle listener started with staus Unknown

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i was started Oracle listener,but it was started with status unknown
due to this i'm not able to connect connect with SQL Developer Tool
it showing error like 
    Status : Failure -test failed: IO Error : The Network Adaptor could not establist the connection

if i started listener it shows as follows

```
Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network    /admin     /listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ist-354/listener  /alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ist-    354)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 -       Production
Start Date                06-NOV-2016 15:31:30
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin /listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ist-354/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ist-354)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

my listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ist-354)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ist-354)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Comment: I get the same 'UNKNOWN` message when I start the listener on my machine.  The listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files are much the same as well.  What details are you using to connect to SQL Developer?

Comment: hostname:localhost
port:1521
service name:XE

Comment: What is the output of `lsnrctl status`?  Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289096) help?

Comment: @LukeWoodward 
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ist-354)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

Comment: @LukeWoodward  
and i'm not able to connect through sql plus also,
it is giving error like
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Comment: If you're getting those errors then the listener hasn't started. Which user are you attempting to start the listener as?

Comment: @LukeWoodward
system user

Comment: What do you mean by "system user"? `root`, `oracle`, a user named `system` or something else?  For best results, start the listener as `oracle`.

Comment: user name :system,
how to connect as oracle?

how to solve ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Comment: when @lukewoodward says start as oracle he means as the user who installed and owns the binaries, which is usually "oracle". I woudl start by doing lsnrctl, then from the prompt stop, then start and see what comes back., is the database started? can you sqlplus / as sysdba? what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps,

1. turn your listener on.
2. Try "tnsping XE" from ist-354 host.
3. if you can successfully connect using TNS then you firewall is causing this. please check if fire wall is running.

you can have help turning off firewall from this link,

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-redhat-centos-5-6-disable-firewall/